# CakePHP parsing the URI and getting ID

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I have a SEO URL like

```
lieferservice-pizzeria-da-persio-26-offenbach
```

in my bootstrap file I am trying to pase this URL and get ID of a shop which is in this is `26`

Then I can read the database to get infos of the shop. What will be the best way to do this. have no idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that's what routes are for. you can paramatized any part of url and access it in the request.in your case i think you want to combine some sort of a slug with an id separted by dash. that's a piece of cake.

```
Router::connect('/:slug-:id', array('controller' => 'yourController', 'action' => 'yourAction'), array('id' => '[0-9]+','slug' => '[a-zA-z-]+')); 

//inside your action
$id = $this->request->params['id'];
$slug = $this->request->params['slug'];
```

no nee for regex :)

Answer (score 1):

The proposed solution simply removes all non digits so you end up with only digits. This works if you can ensure that you'll never have a digit in your string else than the string. So with a string like 'lieferservice-pizzeria12-da-24-persio-26-offenbach' you would get 122426 instead of the 26 you wanted to.

If you want to ensure that you only accept -somedigit- as id you should use:

```
preg_match("/-([0-9]+)-/", $input_line, $output_array);
```

instead.

What this actually does is really simple:

It simply looks for the first string starting with a "-" followed by exclusive! digits and ending with "-" than it returns the whole string in $output_array[0] (in your example -26-) and the digit (the stuff inside the brackets) in $output_array[1] which equals 26 in your case.

Answer (score 0):

**Best Solution**

```
$str = 'lieferservice-pizzeria-da-persio-26-offenbach';
$int = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]+/', '', $str), 10);
var_dump($int );
```

Its return only `int 26`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a function in your controller, let call it

```
public function getUrl(){

}
```

The first think is to make CakePhp accept the type of URL you are passing (with special characters like "-"). In your route you can have this:

```
Router::connect('/getUrl/:id', array('controller' => 'yourControllerName', 'action' => 'getUrl'), array('id' => '[0-9A-Za-z= -]+'));
```

Now if you pass your URL as

```
www.domain.com/getUrl/lieferservice-pizzeria-da-persio-26-offenbach
```

Then back to your function

```
public function getUrl(){
  $getValueFromUrl = $this->params['id'];
  // Use PHP explode function to get 26 out of $getValueFromUrl

}
```